# How do I cycle an odd/even class as it loops over the items?

Tags: jquery-templates

Using the jquery-tmpl, I want to stripe presentation of the rows by adding a class to every second one, so from data ['Cat','Dog','Horse','Noddy'] it generates:

```
<li>Cat</li>
<li class="odd">Dog</li>
<li>Horse</li>
<li class="odd">Noddy</li>
```

The solutions [suggested here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7137#comment:2) looked like the start of something that could be further refined for easy digestion by us noddy's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never mind. Overcomplicating things as usual...

Just follow it up with the :odd selector with addClass...

```
$('#template').tmpl(data).appendTo('#list')
$("#list li:odd").addClass('odd')
```

Answer (score 3):

Just found the solution after few trial and errors. You can use the {{= }} tag for evaluating expression:

```
{{each(i) Animals}}<li class="{{= i % 2 ? 'even' : 'odd'}}">...</li>{{/each}}
```

Of course you can modify it to suit your needs exactly - you can put the class inside and print empty value for odd or even.

Another solution would be to use a function (there is example of this in the jquery tmpl docs), but it is ugly.

Comment: works brilliant. use this if you don't want to write any JS code!!

Answer (score 0):

@John Mee, I don't think you are overcomplicating.

Imho the template is the place where the addition of the odd-Class should take place. Logic and performance wise.

[Here](https://github.com/clarkbox/jquery-tmpl/commit/993e6fa128c5991723316032abe12ff0cbbb9805#diff-0) is a patch for having the index inside a nested template. If you like to have an additional $odd property it could be easily extended as follows:

```
jQuery.map( data, function( dataItem, index ) {
    if(dataItem){
         dataItem.$index = index;
         dataItem.$odd = index % 2 === 1;
    }
```